# Getting the contents of a UL tag to post to database

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am using the "tagit" code on my site which looks like this..

```
<script src="http://webspirited.com/tagit/demo/js/jquery.1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://webspirited.com/tagit/demo/js/jquery-ui.1.8.20.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://webspirited.com/tagit/js/tagit.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://webspirited.com/tagit/demo/css/jquery-ui-base-1.8.20.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://webspirited.com/tagit/css/tagit-awesome-blue.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
    $('#topic').tagit({triggerKeys:['enter', 'comma', 'tab'], select:true});     

    $('#otopictags').click(function () {
        showTags($('#topic').tagit('tags'))
    });
        $('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
    tag = $('#topic').tagit('tags');
    console.log(tag);
    for (var i in tag)
      $('form').append("<input type='hidden' name='tags[]' value='"+tag[i].value+"' >");

  });
    function showTags(tags) {
        console.log(tags);
        var string = "Tags (label : value)\r\n";
        string += "--------\r\n";
        for (var i in tags)
            string += tags[i].label + " : " + tags[i].value + "\r\n";
        alert(string);
    }
});
```

```
<form method="post" action="add_topic.php">
<ul id="topic" name="tag"></ul>
```

Add_topic.php looks like

```
$tag = $tag;

$sql = "INSERT INTO tags (tag) VALUES('$tag')";
```

I wanted to get the tag part working before adding the additional data, the query is posting without errors, but in the database empty data is being inserted.

Can anyone offer advice on using the post method I posted above to successful insert the tag contents into the database or even a possible tutorial site link on how to install? I can't find anything on it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you're not assigning any values to `$tag` variable. It is empty.

To assign the form input to `$tag`, you need something like this:

```
$tag = $_POST['tag'];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! knew I would be overlooking something, I got it posting, but I put in 3 tags and it only posted the last one :(

Answer (score 0):

`<ul id="topic" name="tag"></ul>` will not be submitted on form post it should be any input type.

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
<html>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" id="topic" name="tag" value="rajeev"/>
</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does that method separate the tags? var_dump? I got it posting via something someone else shared, but it only posted the last tag.

Comment: @user2571547 access post data like $_POST['tag']